# Long transfer function is running out of margin

Tags: equations, line-breaking, align, miktex

My equation is large and it runs out of the margin.

I tried align, aligned and other things but non of them scaling the equations properly.

Here is my equation:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:serial_Vo}
 V_o = \frac{C_2 C_1 L_3 R_L R_0 s^3}{\big(C_2 C_1 L_2 L_3 R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_3 R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_2 R_0\big) s^4 + \big(C_2 C_1 L_3 R_L R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_3 R_i R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_2 R_i R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_1 R_L R_0\big) s^3 + \big(C_2 C_1 R_i R_L R_0 + C_1 L_3 R_0 + C_1 L_1 R_0 + C_2 L_2 R_0\big) s^2 + \big(C_1 R_i R_0 + C_2 R_L R_0\big) s + R_0}
\end{equation}
```

I am a beginner for Latex and please let me know how can I split this equation to best represent it inside the margins.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you abbreviate the very long denominator and call it, say, `X`, and that you provide a separate, multi-line display-math environment to list the contents of `X`. (You're free to choose a different character or symbol for the denominator term...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:serial_Vo}
V_o = \frac{C_2 C_1 L_3 R_L R_0 s^3}{X}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
X&=\bigl(C_2 C_1 L_2 L_3 R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_3 R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_1 L_2 R_0\bigr) s^4 \\
&\quad+ \bigl(C_2 C_1 L_3 R_L R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_3 R_i R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_2 R_i R_0 + C_2 C_1 L_1 R_L R_0\bigr) s^3 \\
&\quad+ \bigl(C_2 C_1 R_i R_L R_0 + C_1 L_3 R_0 + C_1 L_1 R_0 + C_2 L_2 R_0\bigr) s^2 \\
&\quad+ \bigl(C_1 R_i R_0 + C_2 R_L R_0\bigr) s + R_0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```